# How integrate stand alone barcode scanner in Android Projects?

Tags: java, android

This is my code....I integrated Zxing library in to my project but its still asking for third party app to use.Help me plz.
mBtnDoScan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (mMode.equals("ie")) {

        int sizeOfList = mInvDetLst.size();

        if (sizeOfList > 0) {
            // instantiate ZXing integration class
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(
                    DeliveryDetail.this);
            // start scanning
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(DeliveryDetail.this,
                    "Items not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }

}
});
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? What third party app is it requesting?

Comment: Well, you a barcode image, so either you integrate it in your app or you need to call Android camera or Gallery app to choose which image to use.

Comment: @TmKVU When I press Scan button it shows"Barcode application is not installed in your app.Would you like to install it?"